# Validating a decimal 3.4 in the XSD schema ^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$

Tags: regex, xml, validation, xsd

I need to mount an XSD to validate a decimal number 3.4. The entire piece can have up to 3 characters and the fraction part is not mandatory, but if any, need to have up to 4 characters.

The regular expression ^[0-9]{1,3}(?:.[0-9]{1,4})?$ works in the test sites, but when I put in the XSD get the error: "InvalidRegex: Pattern value '^[0-9]{1,3}(?:.[0-9]{1,4})?$' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This expression is not supported in the current option setting.' at column '{2}'."

XSD Schema:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="st_decimal7-4">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
  <xs:pattern value="^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$"/>      
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="teste">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="valor" type="st_decimal7-4" />
  </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have non-capturing groups there and start/end signs. Just change the line with the pattern to this and you're good to go:

```
<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?"/>
```

Comment: You might also want to add `-?` at the beggining of your regex to support negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are using several constructs that are not available in the XSD-defined regular expression syntax. (Some schema processors, e.g. Microsoft, are known to ignore this syntax and just use whatever works in the regular expression library that they use internally).

The disallowed constructs include ^ and $ (not needed because the regex is implicitly anchored), and "(?"